# PHP Error: call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a php script which should connect to a database, check whether a row with the given field exists and, if it exists, update another field of the same row. However, the UPDATE query seems to fail, and I can't see why. I tried to google the problem but couldn't find a working solution. I tried to `echo($mysqli->error)` but it gave me an empty string.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "../config.php";

if(isset($_GET['actionForgot']) && !empty($_GET['restore'])) {
    $piva=trim($_GET['restore']);
    $mysqli = new mysqlc();
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username,email FROM login WHERE piva = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $piva);
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        trigger_error('The query execution failed; MySQL said ('.$stmt->errno.') '.$stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    $stmt->bind_result($username, $email);
    if($stmt->fetch()) {
        $password = generatePassword(10);
        $crypPass = MD5($password);
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE login SET password = ? WHERE piva = ?"); //Here's the error!
        if(!$stmt->bind_param("ss",$crypPass,$piva)){
            echo "fail";
        } else if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            trigger_error('The query execution failed; MySQL said ('.$stmt->errno.') '.$stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
            echo "fail"; 
        } else {
            sendEmailRestore($username, $password, $email);  
            echo $email; 
        } 
    } else {
        echo "nexists";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}else{
    echo "false";
}
?>
```

P.S. I'm sure the problem is not in config.php because other similar php scripts work just fine.

EDIT: Could it have something to do with the fact I'm using the same variable `$stmt` for two queries?

Comment: Well if `$stmt` is not an object, as the error message proves, then the assignment fails which means that the `prepare()` method fails to prepare the statement. You should try to use that statement inside an interactive session to your database server, most likely it will throw an error.

Comment: @arkascha I tried to manually insert the query via phpmyadmin, as `UPDATE login SET password = "test" WHERE piva = "some_existing_value"` and it worked like a charme. That's why this is driving me nuts!

Comment: use try catch for prepare and binding

Comment: BTW: what is `new mysqlc();`? Is `$mysqli` an object at all?

Comment: @Awlad Liton: and how should that help me? That error means the whole script failed: there's no point in catching it. Prepared statements provide much more effective methods of handling errors, but still this one shouldn't happen...

Comment: @arkascha: The class mysqlc() is just a derived class from mysqli() whose connection parameters are already defined in its constructor. I'm 100% sure that mysqlc() works just fine, because it worked with previous php script.

Comment: Tripple check what `$mysqli` actually is. Dump the object. Retrieve a state from it. And post the implementation of `mysqlc` here, we cannot _guess_ it.

Comment: Yes, I understand: whenever `prepare()` fails, it returns `false`, so my `$stmt` is not an object but just a `false` value. There problem here is WHY is `prepare()` not returning an object?

Comment: Well best probably is if you start using a debugger to step through the code. Sooner or later you have to start using one anyway. So better do it now whilst things are still easy. Inside the debugger session you can take a look at all values, objects and states without hassle.

Comment: Use mysqli->errno() to find the error: [mysqli error reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: Look at all these exact duplicates you ignored when you posted http://i.imgur.com/9CQTw13.png

Comment: @Marcel Balzer: It prints Errorcode: 0...

Comment: @Mike B: I'm perfectly aware of them. I read through all of them with to no avail: I always do before posting a question. My problem seems to be pretty specific, otherwise it would have been solved already. Next time think twice before downvoting: I can't see anything incorrect with my posting behavor.

Comment: @LorDisturbia You read through all [200+ dupes](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+bind_param%28%29+on+a+non-object+is%3Aquestion) and none of them helped? Doubtful. You must have also seen the hugely negative net-vote count for such questions. Don't be surprised when your question receives the same treatment. Running a very basic php mysqli query CAN'T be this difficult as there's thousands of tutorials covering everything. You're making this harder than it needs to be. Follow sscce.org (debug your own code) and I'll bet you'll find the problem without handholding.

Comment: @Mike B: as you can see by the answer I posted, the problem was really specific. I've read about 50 of the other duplicates, and 99% of them where syntax errors (which I made sure wasn't my case). The other 1% was some code which I found really complicated to read, and still had nothing to do with my case. I might be a newbie, but I sure know how to behave, and this seemed by far the best approach to my problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found the problem! It had something to do with `$mysqli` being used for two different queries. I have no idea why this should give problems of any kind, but I changed the code to this:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "../config.php";

if(isset($_GET['actionForgot']) && !empty($_GET['restore'])) {
    $piva=trim($_GET['restore']);
    $mysqli = new mysqlc();
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username,email FROM login WHERE piva = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $piva);
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        trigger_error('The query execution failed; MySQL said ('.$stmt->errno.') '.$stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    $stmt->bind_result($username, $email);
    if($stmt->fetch()) {
        $password = generatePassword(10);
        $crypPass = MD5($password);
        $mysqli2 = new mysqlc(); //NOTICE THIS LINE
        $stmt = $mysqli2->prepare("UPDATE login SET password = ? WHERE piva = ?"); //AND THIS
        if(!$stmt->bind_param("ss",$crypPass,$piva)){
            echo "fail";
        } else if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            trigger_error('The query execution failed; MySQL said ('.$stmt->errno.') '.$stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
            echo "fail"; 
        } else {
            sendEmailRestore($username, $password, $email);  
            echo $email; 
        } 
    } else {
        echo "nexists";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}else{
    echo "false";
}
?>
```

and it works just fine.
I'd still like to know why I was doing it wrong, though...